# I generates permutations with duplicating only the item not the collection, and I want to generalize the function for number of items in collection

Tags: c#

I a trying to get permutations of an array with duplicating only the array item in a collection and not duplicating the collection as a whole

I figured out a solution but I should code for loops manually as much as the number of items in a collection
How to generalize this solution for number of items in collection and generate multiple nested for based on the number of items in collection

```
 public static List<List<float>> Permute( float [] array, int numberOfItemsInCollection=3)
        {
            var collections = new List<List<float>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
                for (int j = i; j <array.Length; j++)
                    for (int k = j; k < array.Length; k++)
                        collections.Add(new List<float> { array[i], array[j], array[k]});
            
            return collections;
        }
```

i.e if i have an array {1,2,3,4} the result is like the following

```
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
1,1,4
1,2,2
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,3
1,3,4
1,4,4
2,2,2
2,2,3
2,2,4
2,3,3
2,3,4
2,4,4
3,3,3
3,3,4
4,4,4
```

Thanks a lot for the first answer, that worked well. I tried to add sum to the collection and edit the code as the following but stackoverflow error occured

```
public static void Permute(int[] prices, int[] volumes, int numberOfItemsInCollection, int k, List<int> curr, int sumPrice, int sumVolume,List<List<int>> ans)
        {
            if (curr.Count == numberOfItemsInCollection)
            {
                curr.Add(sumPrice);
                curr.Add(sumVolume);
                ans.Add(new List<int>(curr));
                sumPrice = 0;
                sumVolume = 0;
                return;
            }
            for (int i = k; i < prices.Length; i++)
            {
                curr.Add(prices[i]);
                sumPrice+=prices[i];
                sumPrice+=volumes[i];
                Permute(prices, volumes, numberOfItemsInCollection, i, curr,sumPrice, sumVolume, ans);
                curr.RemoveAt(curr.Count - 1);
            }

        }
        public static List<List<int>> Permute(int[] prices, int[] volumes, int numberOfItemsInCollection)
        {
            List<List<int>> ans = new List<List<int>>();
            Permute(prices, volumes, numberOfItemsInCollection, 0, new List<int>(),0,0, ans);
            return ans;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the code in java language. you can easily convert the same on the language you want.

```
 public static void Permute(int [] array, int numberOfItemsInCollection,int k,List<Integer> curr,List<List<Integer>> ans)
        {
            if(curr.size()==numberOfItemsInCollection) {
                ans.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
                return ;
            }
            for (int i = k; i < array.length; i++) {
                curr.add(array[i]);
                Permute(array, numberOfItemsInCollection, i, curr, ans);
                curr.remove(curr.size() - 1);
            }
           
        }
        public static List<List<Integer>> Permute(int [] array, int numberOfItemsInCollection){
            List<List<Integer>> ans=new ArrayList<>();
            Permute(array,numberOfItemsInCollection,0, new ArrayList<>(), ans);
            return ans;
        }
```

Comment: The above solution gives combination. If you want permutation you can replace "i=k" with "i=0".

Comment: Thanks a lot , that worked well. I tried to add sum to the collection and edit the code as the following but stackoverflow error occured, please look at the edit I done above